# Facebook event subscription to auth.logout only selectively redirects user to a url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

So I have the following code that implements a facebook button on a welcome page that redirects to a user page:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'myappid',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        window.top.location = 'user url';
      }
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```

The button works fine, and it redirects to the user page. My code for the user page is:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'myappid',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.top.location = 'welcome page url';
    });

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```

Which shows me a log out button on the user page after successfully logging in, which is awesome. However, clicking the facebook log out button does not redirect me back to the welcome page; it just stays at the user page, except the button now changes back to a log in button. However if I use the fb log in button while in the user page, then use the fb button to log out, now it redirects me back to the welcome page.

I'm not sure why the fb log out button redirects me only if I logged in on the user page, and not when I log in through the welcome page. Is there a different way to do a redirection after using the fb log out button? Subscribing to auth.StatusChange and auth.authResponseChange doesn't work either. I'm using Ruby on Rails, if it matters, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  ...
});
```

after

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
  ...
});
```

in the user view works, now the logout button redirects back to the welcome page. I'm not sure why this works, since the FB.getLoginStatus part doesn't do anything right now. I'm thinking that the getLoginStatus somehow notifies/triggers/allows the FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout') to run/notice that the user isn't logged in.